# memory problems with class from linked library

Tags: c++, boost, clang, static-libraries

I have a static library with some basic boost graph functionality, all encapsulated in the class 'vgraph'.

When instantiating the class with a shared pointer it doesn't work, everything seems unallocated.
If I don't use a pointer it seems to be OK.

What am I missing? When the code used in the static library was integrated in the main source everything worked ok with smart pointers. No problems at all.

sample code:

```
    #ifndef testClass_hpp
    #define testClass_hpp

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <vector>
    #include <string>
    #include <random>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <memory>

    class vGraph { // from the static library
         public:
        vGraph();
        ~vGraph();

        void test();
        unsigned long addVertex(bool _di);
        void addEdge(unsigned long a, unsigned long b, bool _di = true);

        int getNumVerts(bool di);
        int getNumEdges(bool di);

        std::vector<std::string> computeXD(bool choice);
        std::vector<std::string> computeXDdi(bool choice);
        int unlinkEdge(int a, int b);
        int linkDiEdge(int a ,int b);
};


        class testClass {
public:
            void randomGraph();
            std::shared_ptr<vGraph> graph;

    };



    #endif /* testClass_hpp */


    #include "testClass.hpp"
    void testClass::randomGraph() {
        graph = std::make_shared<vGraph>();

        std::vector<unsigned long> verts;

        for (int i=0; i<2000; ++i) {
            verts.push_back(graph->addVertex(true));
        }
        std::cout << graph->getNumVerts(true);
        for (int i=0; i<5000; ++i) {
            graph->addEdge(std::rand()%2000, std::rand()%2000);
        }
        graph->computeXDdi(true);
    }
```

#

```
void main(){
testClass test;
    test.randomGraph();
}
```

#

If I replace std::shared_ptr graph with a simple vGraph graph, everything seems ok. 
Stupid lack of knowledge?

EDIT to make things a bit more clear.

Compile work with no errors. On runtime and if I declare the vGraph inside the testClass as an std::shared_ptr I get unallocated memory errors.

like:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x648000021ce0: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Like things are not properly initialised inside the vGraph object if I use the shared pointer.

Comment: Don't you mean `testClass test;` in your `main` function?

Comment: correct! testClass test.

Comment: "When instantiating the class with a shared pointer it doesn't work,", what doesnt work ? Are you getting any compilation error or something ?

Comment: State your problem - describe current output (behaviour, compilation error, segfault occurrence etc) and described you expected output (for e.g. expected behaviour)

Comment: compiles fine but I get unallocated memory problems if I try to add one vertex to the graph. its like no proper initialisation happened. see edit.

Comment: There's a lot of code that you don't show that could cause this, and it's impossible to know which.  You should really learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because the code you show is not enough. You should also learn how to use a debugger to catch crashes like that, because if you do then the debugger will stop at the location of the crash, and let you examine and walk up the function call stack to your code, where you can examine values of variables. At the very least show us where in your code the crash happens.

Comment: indeed not the best example but I tried to do my best by writing this simple example. The error comes from within boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, VertexProperties, EdgeWeightProperty>, when I try to add the first vertex. Was if no initialisation has happen (if I use a pointer). While if I don't use a pointer like "vGraph graph" (and not std::shared_ptr<vGraph> graph) everything is ok.

Any C++ book targeting library coding?

Answer (score -1):

> If I replace std::shared_ptr graph with a simple vGraph graph, everything seems ok. Stupid luck of knowledge?

If I got it right, this doesn't work:

```
void main(){
    std::shared_ptr<vGraph> graph;
    test.randomGraph();
}
```

But this does:

```
void main(){
    vGraph test;
    test.randomGraph();
}
```

My understanding is that declaring a `std::share_ptr<vGraph>` will just declare a (shared) **pointer** to a potential *vGraph* object, but declaring a `vGraph` object, as expected, will declare and define a statically allocated object.

Comment: Nope. OP clearly stated, that is using `graph = std::make_shared<vGraph>();`, so this will dynamically allocate object.

Comment: the original post had a couple of spellings in the code! in the main I initialise testClass test. not the graph.